# How to use ehcache-spring-annotations to cache bulk data at application startup

Tags: ehcache

I am using [ehcache-spring-annotations](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/UsingCacheable) to cache my application data.

I have below method for same:

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "myCache")
public Customer load(Long customerId) {
      return new Customer("Narendra", 34);
}
```

My requirement is that, I want to load all customers into cache at application startup not each time when I call `load(long customerId)` method. Is there any way in `ehcache-spring-annotations` where I can store all customers into cache with single method call?

For example: If I have customers map like `Map<Long, Customer>` which is fetched at application startup and I want to have kind of below method which can help to store all customers into cache with single method call

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "myCache")
public Customer putAll(Map<Long, Customer> allCustomers) {
  //Other Code here
}
```

Comment: Did you find a workaround or solution on this?

Comment: I have to load it manually during server start up.